# Can not create VPN Client in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have one problem I want to create VPN Endpoint in AWS but it seem message error permission deny and I try to take root account to create role also not possible.

[image: Can not create VPN endpoint]
[image: Can not create ROLE]

Answer (score 1):

Please read AWS docs on what are and how to use trust policies:

- [How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/)

Trust policies **do not have** `resource` and they use `sts:AssumeRole` in Actions.